# Calculation of GCD of two polynomials

Tags: polynomials, proof-explanation, finite-fields, gcd-and-lcm

I want to know the method he used [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1478283/i-have-to-find-a-splitting-field-of-x6-3-over-mathbbf-7#comment3010192_1478317) to find the gcd of $x^{49}-x$ and $x^6-3$ in $\mathbb{F}_7[x]$. It seems that he is not using Euclidean algorithm but rather uses the reduction by replacing $x^6=3$ in $x^{49}-x$. I want to understand why and how it works. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first step of the Euclidean algorithm yields $q,r\in\Bbb{F}_7[x]$ such that
$$x^{49}-x=q\cdot(x^6-3)+r,$$
with $\deg r<6$, and $\gcd(x^{49}-x,x^6-3)$ divides $r$. Reducing mod $x^6-3$ then shows that
$$r\equiv x^{49}-x\pmod{x^6-3}.$$
Of course we can reduce $x^{49}-x$ mod $x^6-3$ by replacing $x^6$ with $3$, yielding
$$r\equiv x^{49}-x\equiv(x^6)^8\cdot x-x\equiv x\pmod{x^6-3}.$$
As $\deg r<6$ this shows that $r=x$. It follows that $\gcd(x^{49}-x,x^6-3)$ divides $x$, from which it quickly follows that the $\gcd$ equals $1$.

Comment: In the last equality, why $(x^6)^8\cdot x-x\equiv x$?

Comment: @love_sodam I have omitted some intermediate steps; plug in $x^6=3$ and simplify.

Answer (score 2):

Another argument is that $x^6-3$ is *irreducible* in $\Bbb F_7[x]$, and $x^{7^2}-x$ splits completely into linear and quadratic factors. In particular, $x^{49}-x$ has no factor irreducible of degree $6$.

Edit: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3857705/xqn-x-is-a-product-of-all-monic-irreducible-polynomial-in-mathbbf-qx).

Comment: I thought so. Also, is there an easy way to see that $x^6-3$ is irreducible? It is clear that it has no linear factors, but what about quadratic or cubic?

Comment: @Servaes Yes, see [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1481456/is-x6-3-irreducible-over-mathbbf-7). So it is well known here.